MAUI CollectionView Parent value to children example/guidance needed
This should (hopefully) be an easy thing to answer. I have a collection view that is bound to a JSON data source, and a button in the first level of the JSON file that I store a value for (in Preferences) and change the button based on if it's stored or not (color, text changes). It then creates a child collection view, which each of the items also have a button for a similar function, except that if the first button is clicked, I want to be able to hide the buttons that are for the children.
Think of it as this: you have a list of box of different types of unique widgets. The parent button allows you to click to save that you own all of the widgets without having to click on each one, but if you haven't clicked the full box, and you only own Widget A, I want to allow you to select Widget A and have it track that you own only Widget A. So, to accomplish scenario one, I want to have a user click the parent button, which would then make all of the buttons in the child area for that parent not visible so that it won't get confusing having the child buttons there if the parent is marked as owned.
I have the collection views set up, the buttons created, and function that saves whether one or the other is owned, and it all works great. I just can't find any examples that aren't extremely complicated with code that obfucsates what to do on a conceptual level. I thought about doing an observable object, but not sure how to accomplish that when there are multiple parent objects. I also found something about ancestor binding, but I couldn't find an example that explained it all very well. One of my coworkers suggested looping through the child controls, but I haven't found a good example of that, and not sure how well that would work.
Here is a (very) trimmed down example of the XAML file:
<CollectionView x.Name="ParentCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding Parent}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Frame>
              <Button Text="{Binding ParentOwned}" Clicked="OwnedButtonClick" WidthRequest="100"></Button>
              <ScrollView>
                    <CollectionView x.Name="ChildCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding Child}>
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Frame>
                                    <Button Text="{Binding ChildOwned}" Clicked="OwnedButtonClick" WidthRequest="100"></Button>
                                </Frame>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                     </CollectionView>
                 </ScrollView>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

Of course, it's FAR more complicated than this, but I want to keep the question and solution as simple as possible for clarity sake (and for those who may come in behind me with the same question).
Haven't really tried much at the moment, as I haven't found a good direction to go with it yet.

Nested collection views are generally a very bad idea.  Have you considered using Grouping instead?

Fairly new to MAUI, does Grouping allow for binding a list from a MVVM object to be bound to it as a child of the main binding? Finding any actual real information on MAUI that's not either too simplistic to be useful, or so overly complex as to be difficult to implement seems to be a bit tough, so I'm just trying to muddle my way through learning all of this by trial and error. If you have any examples of Grouping that show how to use it as opposed to this, that would be fantastic! Also, just curious, what's the reason for nested collections being bad?

You can check this document about Collectionview.

Frame is also not recommended to use in .NET MAUI. If you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use Border instead.

Short answer:
public partial class Class_ParentChild_Model : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    Class_ParentModel _ParentModel = new();
    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<Class_ChildModel> _OB_ChildModel = new();
}

ObservableCollection<Class_ParentChild_Model> OB_ParentChild_Model { get; } = new();



<CollectionView x.Name="ParentCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding OB_ParentChild_Model }">
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Frame>
        <Button Text="{Binding ParentModel.ParentOwned}" Clicked="OwnedButtonClick" WidthRequest="100"></Button>
        <ScrollView>
            <CollectionView x.Name="ChildCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding OB_ChildModel}>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame>
                        <Button Text="{Binding ChildOwned}" Clicked="OwnedButtonClick" WidthRequest="100"></Button>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </ScrollView>
        </Frame>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>



Thanks Mustafa, have an additional question for you on this: The parent model class is actually a MVVM class that I set in the code behind for the page to be the source (so I'm not technically using the ItemsSource in the first CollectionView in the XAML to bind it). This is due to the fact I'm reading in a locally saved JSON file. Would I then create the partial class in your reply, then set that observable class to the JSON source? I take it I would leave the binding for the ParentModel in your response as is, and just set the OB_ParentChild_Model to the JSON source?

Welcome, for that, there is no need for Class_ParentChild_Model or Grouping as suggested by @Jason, just take the code inside Class_ParentChild_Model and use it, as you said on the last part of your comment

Thanks again, Mustafa! I'll have some time this weekend to work on this, so I'll definitely be trying this out then!
